# use named JSON Objects in Java

Tags: java, json

I want to process a JSON file in the following format: I want the data
in the file to be `JSONObject` objects in Java.

However I'm confused by the fact, that the objects in the File have a name and I can't find other examples for this kind of JSON documents online.

Please suggest.

```
{
"bazaar": {
    "21943236": {
        "cost": 69750,
        "quantity": 287
    },
    "20824133": {
        "cost": 69960,
        "quantity": 500
    },
    "21885344": {
        "cost": 69999,
        "quantity": 30
    },
    "10109747": {
        "cost": 70000,
        "quantity": 18
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that complex to work with. For example, if you had the class

```
class BazaarItem {
    String id;
    int cost;
    int quantity;

    public BazaarItem(String id, int cost, int quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Then you can parse the JSON object (I am using the org.json library here)

```
String json = "your json";
JSONObject bazaar = new JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("bazaar");
```

and then, by iterating over the keys, you either convert it to a list

```
List<BazaarItem> items = new ArrayList<>(bazaar.size());
for (String key : bazaar.keys()) {
    JSONObject value = items.getJSONObject(key);

    int id = Integer.parseInt(key);
    int cost = value.getInt("cost");
    int quantity = value.getInt("quantity");
    items.add(new BazaarItem(id, cost, quantity));
}
```

or convert it to a map.

```
Map<Integer, BazaarItem> items = new HashMap<>(bazaar.size());
for (String key : bazaar.keys()) {
    JSONObject value = items.getJSONObject(key);

    int id = Integer.parseInt(key);
    int cost = value.getInt("cost");
    int quantity = value.getInt("quantity");
    items.put(id, new BazaarItem(id, cost, quantity));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the library you're using, JSONObject is likely to implement `Map<String, Something>`.

This gives you all the names of the objects contained, by calling bazaar.keySet().

So it would be like:

```
JsonObject bazaar = howeverYouLikeToObtainTheBazaarObject();

for(String name : bazaar.keySet()) {
  JSONObject costQuantity = bazaar.getJsonObject(name);
  // do stuff with name and costQuantity
}
```